# Google Earth Pro: touring waypoints without a "bounce"

Tags: python, kml, google-earth

In Google Earth Pro (GEP) I want to record a tour, which travels from A through B to C. At point B, the tour camera does what I think is called a bounce: it drops down a little toward point B, waits a while, then lifts up and continues. Is there a way to set a tour to just go through the waypoint B, with an even speed, without doing the bounce? In GEP Options, under "Touring", I don't see a way to disable the bounce. Alternatively, I could export the tour as a KML/KMZ and edit it outside. Is there some user-friendly KML/KMZ tool that allows such edits? I can do Python KML/KMZ hacking, too, if needed, but I'd prefer to start from the easiest possible solution. Thanks.